# Exception Handling in Dynamics CRM SDK

Tags: c#, exception, dynamics-crm

I am currently developing a simple **Dynamics CRM** Application which allows the user to create new entities records.

So when an error occurred I get the full stack, but I'm wondering if I could get the attribute name responsible for that error.

Comment: I just finished creating some incidents from C# and my exceptions specifically told me which attribute was at fault.  I am using VS 2017 and simply selected the exception in the Events window while debugging.  For example System.ServiceModel.FaultException in Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll ('incident' entity doesn't contain attribute with Name = 'new_backupState')

Comment: This really depends on the specific error you are getting. As @DavidYenglin shows it is certainly possible, but it may not be true in all cases. Often it depends on whether the platform throws an error or a plugin throws the error. What attribute exceptions are you seeing that don't provide the attribute name? Also, please let us know the version of CRM and whether it is online or on-premise.

Answer (score 4):

When you want to avoid emitting full stack traces for known CRM platform errors, you can catch errors of type `FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault>` and handle them in an appropriate way, like this:

```
try
{
    service.Create(entity);
}
catch (FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault> ex)
{
   switch (ex.Detail.ErrorCode)
   {
       case 0x80041103: // QueryBuilderNoAttribute
          Console.WriteLine(ex.Detail.Message);
          // Specific error handling goes here...
          return;

       default:
          throw;
   }
}
```

The platform error codes are documented and can be looked up on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328182(v=crm.8).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

As suggested you can use the following handlers to handle common exceptions with CRM:

```cs
try
{
    // Write your code here !
}
catch (FaultException<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault> ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The application terminated with an error.");
    Console.WriteLine("Timestamp: {0}", ex.Detail.Timestamp);
    Console.WriteLine("Code: {0}", ex.Detail.ErrorCode);
    Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", ex.Detail.Message);
    Console.WriteLine("Inner Fault: {0}",
        null == ex.Detail.InnerFault ? "No Inner Fault" : "Has Inner Fault");
}
catch (System.TimeoutException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The application terminated with an error.");
    Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", ex.Message);
    Console.WriteLine("Stack Trace: {0}", ex.StackTrace);
    Console.WriteLine("Inner Fault: {0}",
        null == ex.InnerException.Message ? "No Inner Fault" : ex.InnerException.Message);
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The application terminated with an error.");
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

    // Display the details of the inner exception.
    if (ex.InnerException != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);

        FaultException<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault> fe = ex.InnerException
            as FaultException<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault>;
        if (fe != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Timestamp: {0}", fe.Detail.Timestamp);
            Console.WriteLine("Code: {0}", fe.Detail.ErrorCode);
            Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", fe.Detail.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Trace: {0}", fe.Detail.TraceText);
            Console.WriteLine("Inner Fault: {0}",
                null == fe.Detail.InnerFault ? "No Inner Fault" : "Has Inner Fault");
        }
    }
}
```

This can also be written and used as

```cs
private T TryCatch<T>(Func<T> action)
        {
            try
            {
                return action();
            }
            catch (FaultException<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault> ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The application terminated with an error.");
                Console.WriteLine("Timestamp: {0}", ex.Detail.Timestamp);
                Console.WriteLine("Code: {0}", ex.Detail.ErrorCode);
                Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", ex.Detail.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("Inner Fault: {0}",
                    null == ex.Detail.InnerFault ? "No Inner Fault" : "Has Inner Fault");
            }
            catch (System.TimeoutException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The application terminated with an error.");
                Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("Stack Trace: {0}", ex.StackTrace);
                Console.WriteLine("Inner Fault: {0}",
                    null == ex.InnerException.Message ? "No Inner Fault" : ex.InnerException.Message);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The application terminated with an error.");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

                // Display the details of the inner exception.
                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);

                    FaultException<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault> fe = ex.InnerException
                        as FaultException<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault>;
                    if (fe != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Timestamp: {0}", fe.Detail.Timestamp);
                        Console.WriteLine("Code: {0}", fe.Detail.ErrorCode);
                        Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", fe.Detail.Message);
                        Console.WriteLine("Trace: {0}", fe.Detail.TraceText);
                        Console.WriteLine("Inner Fault: {0}",
                            null == fe.Detail.InnerFault ? "No Inner Fault" : "Has Inner Fault");
                    }
                }
            }

            //return
            return default(T);
        }
```

Where you just have to call:

```cs
return TryCatch<int>(()=> {
    //write code here
    return 5;
});
```

and don't have to write the catch block everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

We can throw an exception and display a message.

throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Message here....");